# Subscription to String in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to replace Subscript  to String, because on android device users can put this value to `EditText` or I want to disable function to show Subscript  char. I want to replace Subscript to string  I did this :

```
public static String fromSubscript(String value) {


    char[] Symbols = new char[] {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '-', '=', '(', ')', '?',  // <- '?' unknown/not standard symbols
            'a', 'e', 'o', 'x', '\u0259', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 's', 't', '?', '?', '?' }; // <- u0259 - small latin shwa

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(value.length());


  for(int i =0; i<value.length();i++){
      char ch = value.charAt(i);
      int v = (int)ch;

      if ((v >= 0x2080) && (v <= 0x209F))
          result.append(Symbols[v - 0x2080]);
      else
          result.append(ch);
  }

    return result.toString();
}





  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a  =  "\u00B9";
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(fromSubscript(a));
    }
```

But it doesn't work correctly it did not change subscript to string

Comment: What is your question here? `0x00B9` is not in the range `0x2080` to `0x209F`?

Comment: @GenoChen for example  I want to change small 1 to normal  1

Comment: So why do you use a test case out of range? You say `if ((v >= 0x2080) && (v <= 0x209F))` then `String a = "\u00B9";`?

Comment: @GenoChen so how I can replece this char ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no question to the code, but your test case has chosen the wrong one. In your code:

```
if ((v >= 0x2080) && (v <= 0x209F))
```

Then you should make a test case within this range, for example:

```
String a = "\u2082";
```

This works well:

```
$ java Test
₂
2
```

---

However, I think there maybe a more common method for doing this, with the help of Unicode Database.

**Update:** `\u00B9` in the original question is **super**script "¹", not **sub**script "₁"(U+2081).

**Super**script is written in the top of character, **sub**script is written in the bottom of character. Your code converts **sub**script well, but you made a test with **super**script, lol.

**Update 2:** For **super**script, the code point for numerals are:

```
'\u2070', '\u00B9', '\u00B2', '\u00B3', '\u2074', '\u2075', '\u2076', '\u2077', '\u2078', '\u2079'
```

Note the discontinuity for **super**script 1 2 and 3 .

Comment: So what I did wrong that it doesn't work for this one ? https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b9/index.htm

Comment: So how it should look like ?

Comment: @tompok What is your actual question? Now you seems asking an X - Y question?